# Python pandas: Write variable to excel cell in existing sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using python pandas to read a large dataset from excel. I then do some calculations and want to write a variable to a single cell in a existing excel file in an existing sheet.

So far I have only seen documentation to write a dataframe with pandas. Is this the way to go? If so, I then will make a dataframe only containing that one variable.

What is the best and easiest way to go forward here?

Answer (score 0):

One option is doing something like this using pandas dataframe and passing only the variable to the dataframe:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("tom_test.xlsx", mode="a", engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
            test = pd.DataFrame([fkbareal_tot])
            test.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet 1", startrow=1, startcol=1, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Probably a lot easier to just use openpyxl directly, `ExcelWriter` is overkill here.